# How to blur part of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

we know that **fabric.Rect** we can mask image.But Providing masking method as 'blur' instead of current gray color overlay is this possible or Is anyone has idea about this

```
    $("#context2Add").click(function () {
    var mask = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill: 'grey',
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });
    fabricCanvas2.add(mask);
});
```

Comment: You can take a look at this example. Use canvas to make blur image http://codepen.io/gakimball/pen/Bafkd

Comment: but i am not expecting this result expecting as freely movable blur rectangle